# Do we need to create schemas in the latest Apache Solr? If yes, then how do I make a schema for a Product with attributes?

Tags: search, solr, solarium

I have an e-commerce store and the table structure of that is as follows:

### Products

```
product_id  | name          price
1             galaxy s9 red     800
2         galaxy s9 blue    850
3                 t-shirt               30
```

### Product Variants

```
procut_variant_id   product_id  variant_name        
1           1       red
2           1       128gb
3           2       blue
4           2       128gb
5                       3               xl
```

I'm submitting the documents through solarium php and this is the format which I've got:
We've got more than 1200 product variants. How do I make a schema for this kind of Data?

Is this okay?
FYI:I have no prior experience in Apache Solr.

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":27,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1550306389227"}},
  "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "name":[" galaxy s9 red"],
        "price":[800],
        "memory":["128GB"],
        "color":["red"],
        "_version_":1625614359718789120},
      {
        "id":"2",
        "name":["galaxy s9 blue"],
        "price":[850],
        "memory":["128GB"],
        "color":["blue"],
        "_version_":1625614359913824256},
      {
        "id":"3",
        "name":["t-shirt"],
        "price":[30],
        "Size":["xl"],
        "_version_":1625614360041750528}]
  }}
```

Comment: Can someone answer this Please?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema looks ok to me. Only thing I notices is that all your fields are `multivalued=true`. I don't think you need it. You have already merged the 2 tables in single solr document.

Mark the fields as `indexed=true` in the schema.xml which are been used in the search.